# Element height seems to jump back and forth whenever I try to scale them based on percentage over a small range

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm using React and Bootstrap for this.

About my code:
I have an element with 0 height, in rem. I want that elements height to increase as I scroll down the page, making it look as if it is appearing out of thin air.

The the `handleWorksTitle` function basically takes the  element and calculates what height it should have based on where its bottom rect is in the window. Once the bottom rect is within the window, we start applying the "animation", and the way I wrote it, the height is calculated as "by this point you gotta have 100% of the target height". The target point is the `bottomPivot.current` which is a percentage of the screen height starting from the bottom.

The code breaks if the window height is too small or if the `bottomPivot.current` value is too low. So basically if the range between the bottom of the screen and the bottom pivot is too short, it breaks.

My code:

```
    function handleWorksTitle() {

        //get the container that we will modify
        const titleCont = document.querySelector("#works-title-cont");

        // the the container's current position (bottom rects pos)
        const currY = titleCont.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

        // if the containers bottom rect pos is within the confines of the screen
        if(currY <= window.innerHeight) {

            // calculate the height target based on screen breakpoint (if its a lg screen we aim for 12, md is 10, sm is 7. All of this is rem units)
            const heightTarget = breakpointStateRef.current == breakpoints.lg ? worksTitleMovLg : (breakpointStateRef.current == breakpoints.md ? worksTitleMovMd : worksTitleMovSm);

            // calculate the height we want to set the element to (in percentage)
            // bittomPivot.current is 30 in this example
            const percentage = GetPerCurrToTarget_Bottom(currY, bottomPivot.current);

            // convert the percentage onto a real value (css's rem unit)
            const value = heightTarget / 100 * percentage;

            // apply the height value
            titleCont.style.height = `${value <= heightTarget ? value : heightTarget }rem`;
        }
    };
```

That function is set up to be called on the window's "scroll" event:

```
// this is a line added to my useEffect([])
window.addEventListener("scroll", handleWorksTitle);
```

This is the GetPerCurrToTarget_Bottom function:

```
export function GetPerCurrToTarget_Bottom(currLoc, targetLoc) {

    const rangeVal = window.innerHeight - targetLoc;// range
    const valInRange = window.innerHeight - currLoc;// where currLoc is
    const percentage = (100 / rangeVal) * valInRange;

    return percentage;
}
```

The code works, in most normal sized screens but as I reduce the height of the screen, it starts to break and I have no idea why. For some reason after a certain screen height the element's Y value will start to oscilate between two numbers, this is the log of the Y value in those cases (which prints as I scroll down):

```
169.10
258.57
140.95
264.43
109.88
250.82
67.27
239
73.48
```

As you can see, is like the element has two values, the 170-ish and the 260-ish. Because of this the element keeps on jumping back and forth in the screen.

Just in case, this is part of my jsx and some css:

```
<div className="col">
    <div id="works-title-cont">
        <p id="works-title" className={CalculateWorksTitleSize(breakpointState)}>Works</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
/* specific to the Works title text */
#works-title-cont {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 0rem;/* this is what we are modifying in code */
    max-height: 100%;

    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

What I expected to happen is for the code to works regardless of the screen's height or the `bottomPivot.current` value (which, if its too low, it breaks the code too).

Comment: I never found a solution to it so I made a workaround.
I discovered that the scroll event for some reason would some times trigger in the opposite direction I was scrolling. So I filtered those out and also stopped tracking where in the window I was. I just used a constant value at which to scale each valid scroll event. Gets the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was just me not understanding how HTML renders things based on CSS' position property (static, relative, absolute)

My element was static and and the trick that I was using was messing with the position of the other elements below it so it caused all kinds of problems.

All I had to do was to set a parent to relative and the child to absolute, then just adjust the position via the transform property.